My queryselectorall throws an error, says addeventlistener is not defined
Please help, I don't know why my queryselectorall is throwing this error, it keeps on saying that addeventlistener is not defined. It works all good with queryselector but throws this error whenever I used queryselectorall. PLease help!!!!


const mytexts = document.querySelectorAll(".my-text");

mytexts.addEventListener("click", function(){
    mytexts.style.color = "red";
})
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
   <div class="my-text">This is my text</div>
   <div class="my-text">This is my text</div>
   <div class="my-text">This is my text</div>
   <div class="my-text">This is my text</div>
    
    
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>




querySelectorAll returns a collection of matching elements. You could use a loop to iterate over the collection and add the event listener on individual elements

To add to the above, you need to loop over that collection of elements and call addEventListener() on each one individually

That's because querySelectorAll returns a NodeList and I don't see any method addEventListener defined on a NodeList so the error is correct.
